# Angular-CLI slow - Chunk asset optimization and asset optimization taking a lot of time

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Chunk asset optimization and asset optimization while developing angular 2 with angular-cli `ng serve` takes a lot of time on my older macbook, eg:

```
9952ms chunk asset optimization
2432ms asset optimization
```

Waiting this time on every change is getting pretty annoying. Is it possible to remove/reduce this time, that his does not happen on every change while developing?

Comment: There's an issue opened here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1980 It's a priority 1 so hopefully we might have an improvement soon !

Comment: Thx, must have missed this one searching

Answer (score 2):

You could look into **--sourcemap=false**.  Seat of the pants improvement:

225ms chunk assets processing, total Time: 38150ms

vs:

215612ms chunk assets processing, total Time: 251719ms

Debugging ability is degraded.  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5423

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. The duration of the compilation process is related to time taken to compile the modules included in app.module.ts.

In my case, I was using angular's InMemoryWebApiModule that was built on top of JSON test-dataset of 9 MB.

So now, when I no longer need the test data, I just comment it out, and the app compiles instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking into this myself, not for this reason but for another one. I don't want to test with the bundled files, I want to test with the 1:1 generated file JS. I was able to do this without the CLI (just using the base 3 files of a typescript project, not webpack etc).

I suspect this is going to be either a tsconfig or webpack setting. I just need to find it.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled a lot with fixing this issue while publishing Angular in production mode.

Following things to do fix 92% chunk asset optimization issue in production mode

**1. Update your nodejs version to the latest.** 
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

**2.Install Angular/Cli**
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

**3.Update Angular/Cli**
ng update @angular/cli
Then Try, if it was taking 110 minutes, after the update it's reduced to less then 2 minutes its reduced around 90%

Before the update, with Dev mode main file is 23 MB and --prod mode 6MB

After the update, the dev mode main file is 9MB and --Prod mode 6MB

Ref:
https://sundarsri.blogspot.com/2018/07/92-chunk-asset-optimization.html